# How to save Pyspark ML model in local system?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-ml

Hi I am not able to save pyspark model in my local folder.
I am using the following code:

```
pipelinePath = './F:/Model_saved/'
pipeline.write().overwrite().save(pipelinePath)
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: And what exactly was the problem? (pls do not respond here, edit & update your question)

Comment: The path is correct? I mean, shouldn't be `'F:/Model_saved/'` instead of `'./F:/Model_saved/'`?

Comment: I also tried with Path 'F:/Model_saved/'.. it still not working....